# Websocket disconnects immediately after connecting (repeatedly)

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/jacobian/channels-example

And I got the error in the title, then I cloned the repository above and got the same error.

(If you are trying to clone the repository to test, remember to change the database settings in settings.py, migrate the database, and go into views and change the `import haikunator` to `from haikunator import Haikunator` and in the `new_room` function add the line `haikunator = Haikunator()` to the beginning of the function so that it will work)

I am using Python 2.7 ad Django 1.10. '

Traceback:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 06, 2017 - 13:22:20
Django version 1.10, using settings 'chat.settings'
Starting Channels development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Channel layer default (asgi_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
2017-07-06 13:22:20,969 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket
.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-07-06 13:22:20,971 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket
.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-07-06 13:22:20,973 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket
.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-07-06 13:22:20,977 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket
.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2017-07-06 13:22:20,986 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2
 and tls Twisted extras)
2017-07-06 13:22:20,992 - INFO - server - Using busy-loop synchronous mode on channel l
ayer
2017-07-06 13:22:20,993 - INFO - server - Listening on endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface
=127.0.0.1
[2017/07/06 13:22:36] HTTP GET /floral-water-4056/ 200 [0.21, 127.0.0.1:23450]
[2017/07/06 13:22:37] HTTP GET /static/normalize.css 304 [0.12, 127.0.0.1:23450]
[2017/07/06 13:22:37] HTTP GET /static/chat.css 304 [0.13, 127.0.0.1:23452]
[2017/07/06 13:22:37] HTTP GET /static/skeleton.css 304 [0.13, 127.0.0.1:23451]
[2017/07/06 13:22:37] HTTP GET /static/jquery-1.12.1.min.js 304 [0.11, 127.0.0.1:23453]

[2017/07/06 13:22:37] HTTP GET /static/reconnecting-websocket.min.js 304 [0.10, 127.0.0
.1:23456]
[2017/07/06 13:22:37] HTTP GET /static/chat.js 304 [0.11, 127.0.0.1:23457]
[2017/07/06 13:22:37] chat connect room=floral-water-4056 client=127.0.0.1:23462
[2017/07/06 13:22:39] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/floral-water-4056/ [127.0.0.1:23462]
[2017/07/06 13:22:40] chat connect room=floral-water-4056 client=127.0.0.1:23465
[2017/07/06 13:22:42] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/floral-water-4056/ [127.0.0.1:23465]
[2017/07/06 13:22:44] chat connect room=floral-water-4056 client=127.0.0.1:23475
[2017/07/06 13:22:47] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/floral-water-4056/ [127.0.0.1:23475]
[2017/07/06 13:22:50] chat connect room=floral-water-4056 client=127.0.0.1:23479
[2017/07/06 13:22:53] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/floral-water-4056/ [127.0.0.1:23479]
[2017/07/06 13:22:57] chat connect room=floral-water-4056 client=127.0.0.1:23482
[2017/07/06 13:23:00] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/floral-water-4056/ [127.0.0.1:23482]
[2017/07/06 13:23:06] chat connect room=floral-water-4056 client=127.0.0.1:23489
[2017/07/06 13:23:08] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/floral-water-4056/ [127.0.0.1:23489]
```

https://github.com/jacobian/channels-example

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem with same repo. The problem for me was the version of channels. I believe that after version 1.10 ( could be wrong on version ), you now have to send back message to reply_channel.

```
message.reply_channel.send({'accept':True})
```

This is not in his code. Probably written prior to change in channels. Once added will stop the disconnects.
See documentation here:
[Channels Documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=%7B%27accept%27%3ATrue%7D&check_keywords=yes&area=default#)

Take a look below at last line of function:

```
def ws_connect(message):
# Extract the room from the message. This expects message.path to be of the
# form /chat/{label}/, and finds a Room if the message path is applicable,
# and if the Room exists. Otherwise, bails (meaning this is a some othersort
# of websocket). So, this is effectively a version of _get_object_or_404.
    try:
        prefix, label = message['path'].strip('/').split('/')
        #log.debug('prefix=%s label=%s', prefix, label)
        if prefix != 'chat':
            log.debug('invalid ws path=%s', message['path'])
            return
        room = Room.objects.get(label=label)
    except ValueError:
        log.debug('invalid ws path=%s', message['path'])
        return
    except Room.DoesNotExist:
        log.debug('ws room does not exist label=%s', label)
        return

    log.debug('chat connect room=%s client=%s:%s', 
        room.label, message['client'][0], message['client'][1])


    Group('chat-'+label, channel_layer=message.channel_layer).add(message.reply_channel)

    message.channel_session['room'] = room.label

    message.reply_channel.send({'accept':True})
```

Comment: Also noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615905/django-channels-websockets-connecting-and-disconnecting-right-away

Comment: This issue still persists in Chrome (even with the accept:True json being returned)... Safari and Firefox work.

Comment: Hmm. I don't have this problem in Chrome.